# How to convert labels(c)[0] in Neo4j cypher query to a PHP cypher DSL?

Tags: php, graph, cypher

I have this code, but am confused about how to convert it to php-cypher-dsl! even ChatGPT doesn't know LOL
BTW: the documentation does not cover all aspects of this great lib, is there another doc?

```
                MATCH (node)-[r]->(c)
                where 
                (labels(c)[0] = "SubCategoryM" or labels(c)[0] = "CategoryM")
                and (c.status=1 OR c.status="1") 
                and id(node)=$node_id
                return 
                id(c) as id,
                c.name as name,
                c.slug as slug
```

https://github.com/neo4j-php/php-cypher-dsl

Thank you

Comment: FYI: in neo4j 5, your query would be better written as `MATCH (node)-->(c:SubCategoryM|CategoryM) WHERE id(node)=$node_id AND c.status IN [1,"1"] RETURN ...`. See the [label expression](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/patterns/reference/#label-expressions) doc.

Comment: This Cypher query may be more easy to convert to php-cypher-dsl (which does not support label expressions): `MATCH (node)-->(c) WHERE id(node)=$node_id AND ANY(lab in ["SubCategoryM", "CategoryM"] WHERE lab IN LABELS(c)) AND c.status IN [1,"1"] RETURN ...`

Comment: Please may you show me example of how to convert it?

Comment: You men like this
`
MATCH (node)-[r]->(c)
WHERE id(node)=$node_id AND c.status IN [1,"1"] AND (c:SubCategoryM OR c:CategoryM)
RETURN 
id(c) AS id,
c.name AS name,
c.slug AS slug
`

Comment: Yes, that is even better Cypher! Take a look at [Node.getLabels](https://github.com/neo4j-php/php-cypher-dsl/blob/ac5a3f289426f2e3174457d7bc47d8d3e112a6c3/src/Patterns/Node.php#L80), which returns an array of label strings for a node. Using the resulting `$labels` you should be able to do something like `in_array("SubCategoryM", $labels) or in_array("CategoryM", $labels)`